# iMessages on iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, messages

Is there any way to use iMessages on an iPhone 3G?

I believe the latest OS it can upgrade to is 4 something, so that might rule out official support by Apple, but what about a 3rd party solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4.2.1 is officially the latest supported version for the iPhone 3G, but you can supposedly install iOS 5 on it with this method: http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/19/install-ios-5-on-iphone-3g-with-whited00r-5/

In the video, it shows the Messages app on the homescreen, so that ought to work for you.

Comment: And when was iMessages introduced? Which iOS version?

Comment: iMessages was introduced in iOS5

Comment: Whited00r just edits the user interface so it looks like newer versions of iOS. In addition it comes with some features that are introduced in newer versions of iOS. However the base version is still the last one that your device supports. So let's say you the first iPhone device that came out. All whited00r versions are built based on iOS 3.1.3